# What is boost::optional efficiency?

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost-optional

I have the following:

```
class Obj;
typedef std::map<string, string> StrMap;
std::map<std::string, std::pair<Obj, StrMap> > complexMap;
```

The thing is that for some entries in complexMap the StrMap will be empty and I won't use it at all, so for efficiency I'm considering to use boost::optional. My question is what's the efficiency of boost::optional, I'm afraid that by paying its price I will gain nothing at the end.

Comment: Have you profiled your code and identified that there is a performance bottleneck due to creation of empty maps?

Comment: @LucTouraille, No. I just wish to have the highest performance I can achieve.

Comment: What alternatives are you considering? The way to find the "highest performance" is to profile different solutions and pick the one with the highest performance.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I don't have the tools to simulate a real system, so I'm interested to know if I pay any price for using boost::optional. If the answer is no, then guess that this is preferred that creating empty maps for vain.

Comment: OK, but what is the alternative you want to compare against?

Comment: Think about how the optional is implemented, it normally has some internal storage (to allow it to the hold the map object - as you would in your code above), and the only difference is that it doesn't construct the map in that storage - this is left for later. However the optional object has to be constructed. So now instead of just constructing a map, you're constructing a bigger optional object in the case where you are not using the map, and when you use the map, you have to construct that too. Seems like you're doing more things for little benefit.

Comment: @Nim, Thanks. You are invited to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of `optional` as a container that can hold 0 or 1 values. Your map already is a container that can hold 0 to N elements. An optional map is therefore a container-in-a-container which can hold 0 to N elements. Really, there's no benefit here.

The overhead of an empty map is quite small. Maps are really built from map nodes, internally, and an empty map just doesn´t have any nodes. (It can´t, because each node holds a value, and there´s no way by which an empty map could create a default value)

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a "sparse" computation, you can do two things:

1. keep a large `complexMap` containing the a lot of non-existing results with a `boost::optional`. This encapsulates the sparseness on a **per-element** basis.
2. create an extra layer of indirection (`unordered_map` e.g.) that contains pointers to the existing elements in your `complexmMap`. This encapsulates the sparseness on a **per-map** basis.

Alternative 1 will be more convenient for you as a programmer, requiring little though at the expense of space overhead. Alternative 2 will be almost perfectly space-efficient and keep `complexMap` as small as possible, but requires more programming work up-front.

Pick whichever alternative is more acceptable to you (hint: if you are doing gigabyte level computation in `complexMap`, maybe the extra level of indirection pays off, otherwise I wouldn't bother).

Other than a space-overhead, there is little other cost to `boost::optional`, since it does not require a default constructor or dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the comment to an answer...

Think about how the optional is implemented, it normally has some internal storage (to allow it to the hold the map object - as you would in your code above), and the only difference is that it doesn't construct the map in that storage - this is left for later. However the optional object has to be constructed. So now instead of just constructing a map, you're constructing a bigger optional object in the case where you are not using the map, and when you use the map, you have to construct that too. Seems like you're doing more things for little benefit.

There are cases where `optional` does make sense (for example return values, where you want to indicate an invalid state for example, or you have a very expensive constructor which does lots of initialization of complex members), for objects with trivial constructors, optional really is not worth the code clutter.

Disclaimer: But as with all performance related questions, profile, profile and then profile again...